# Add Problems In java

Tags: java, addition

I want to take input of two variable as integer and than do addition with the two variables.
The ans will stored in another variable. The program will repeat after every addition end and will ask for user input of varibles and will do addition again.

My qus is taht how can i add all aditions ans again:

Exm:

```
Input a= 5
Input b=5
ans=10
```

Agin program will ask for

```
Input a= 6
Input b= 6
ans=12
```

now how can i take all " ans " value with program and do additions of all "ans"

```
Final Ans=10+12=22
```

code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class math{

        public void add()
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int a;
            int b;

            System.out.print("\nEnter a : ");
            a = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter b : ");
            b = keyboard.nextInt();

            int c=a+b;

            System.out.println("\nans is  :"+c);

            math ob_m=new math();
            ob_m.add();
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            math ob_main=new math();
            ob_main.add();
        }
    }
```

The code just do addition one after another but i want that it will do one more task that ....

It all add all aditions reasuts also. how can i do it?

Comment: Currently your code is only getting called once - you could use a loop - e.g. a while loop or a do while loop to iterate until a certain condition is satisfied - like if the user enters 0 for an input

Comment: Why are you making a new `math` object in the add method, then calling add again? You'll just loop forever adding the same values then refreshing over and over and over...

Comment: @Katana24 The function is called recursively (here - `ob_m.add();`), so it's not just called once.

Comment: aahh - didn't see that - good eyes @Dukeling

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    int a;
    int b;
    int sum = 0;

    public void add() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("\nEnter a : ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter b : ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

        sum = sum + (a + b);

        System.out.println("\nans is  :" + (a + b));

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test ob_main = new Test();
        while (true) {
            ob_main.add();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding the intermediate sums to another variable, so at the end you get the final total.

Another alternative (though not preferable when simple solution is available) is to put these sums in a list and at the end iterate through the list and calculate the final total.

Also, do not use ob_m.add(); - just call add();

Comment: Define instance variable, let's call it "total". Keep adding sum to it - total += c; That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Store every answer in an additional variable. Then when you're done, sum all the answer variables

Comment: can some one an give a example how can create a loop for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for repeating your action, and store each addition in a total sum?

Answer (score 0):

have a field GrandSUM,

```
GrandSum = 0;
```

and after every addition, add ans to it.

```
GrandSum += ans;
```

at the end , GrandSum will have result you want.

Edit:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class math{
    int GrandSum = 0;//added
        public void add()
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int a;
            int b;

            System.out.print("\nEnter a : ");
            a = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter b : ");
            b = keyboard.nextInt();

            int c=a+b;
            GrandSum += c;//added

            System.out.println("\nans is  :"+c);                
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            math ob_main=new math();
            ob_main.add();
            //.....repeat as many times you want
            ob_main.add();
            System.out.println("grandsum: " + ob_main.GrandSum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this wont work... you making new object in each addition so your GrandSum will be every time reseted

Comment: calling the add() on same object multiple times will give correct GrandSum for that particular object.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void add() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    int b;
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a : ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter b : ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

       int c = a+b;
       total += c;
    }
    System.out.println("\nans is  :"+total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a `total` variable which you just keep adding `c` to.

I also changed your unneeded recursion into a while-loop.

```
public class math
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int total = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter a (-999 to quit): ");
            int a = keyboard.nextInt();

            // terminating condition, modify appropriately
            if (a == -999)
                break; // break out of the while-loop

            System.out.print("Enter b: ");
            int b = keyboard.nextInt();

            int c = a + b;
            total += c;

            System.out.println("\nans is: " + c);
        }
        System.out.println("total is: " + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package farzi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String choice = "";
        do{
            System.out.println("enter the first number");
            int a = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the second number");
            int b = keyboard.nextInt();
            int tempSum = a+b;
            list1.add(a);
            list2.add(b);
            sum.add(tempSum);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue : type yes or no");
            choice = keyboard.next();
        }while(choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0)=='y');
        System.out.println("here are the inputs with theri sum");
        System.out.println("num1\t num2\t sum");
        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list1.get(i)+"\t"+list2.get(i)+"\t"+sum.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```